# OrmLite Select within select using SelectArg to escape characters

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using the QueryBuilder to construct the inner SQL that later is used in a raw SQL to avoid escaping invalid characters manually.

```java
SelectArg friendsIN = new SelectArg(friendsUsernames);
QueryBuilder<MyObject, Integer> qb = myObjectDao.queryBuilder();
qb.selectRaw("username", "MAX(time) AS latestTime").groupBy("username").where()
    .in("username", friendsIN);
String innerSelect = pq.getStatement();
```

`friendsUsernames` is defined as `ArrayList<String>`.

Then I use the `innerSelect` to build the outer select:

```java
String select = "SELECT w.id FROM (" + innerSelect +") AS x INNER JOIN myObject AS w on w.username = x.username AND w.time = x.latestTime";
GenericRawResults<String[]> results = myObjectDao.queryRaw(select);
```

But, as expected, the `innerString` has `'?'` and when I call `queryRaw` on `myObjectDao` I don't get any result. I tried to give friendsUsername as an array to queryRaw:

```java
GenericRawResults<String[]> results =
    myObjectrDao.queryRaw(select,
         friendsUsernames.toArray(new String[friendsUsernames.size()]));
```

But I get the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException:
      bind or column index out of range: handle 0x17a22e8
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this kind of queries with OrmLite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah that's not going to work.  There is only one `?` in your query and yet you are trying to pass in an array of user-names.  There must be a 1-to-1 correspondence between the number  of `?` SQL arguments and the number of arguments passed to the `queryRaw(...)` method exactly.

If the `friendsUsernames` is a fixed size then you should be able to do something like the following which will generate SQL something like `"in (?, ?, ?, ?)"`:

```
List<SelectArg> friendsInList = new ArrayList<SelectArg>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FRIENDS; i++) {
   // it doesn't matter what the value is since you just want the ?
   fieldsInList.add(new SelectArg());
}
...in("name", friendsInList);
```

However if the list of names is dynamic then you are going to have to do this on the fly since, again, the number of `?` must match the number of arguments passed to the `queryRaw(...)` method exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that approach. I was assuming that one `?` will allow me to bind an array of strings.

Comment: For those guys llke me who forgot set args in raw query:

DON'T forget include array with all your args as second parameter in raw query!

queryRaw(bondQb.prepareStatementString(), argArray);